# UIcollectionView Reloaddata displays some random data from row below it for a fraction of second before showing actual data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

While reloading UICollectionview, cell which has a chat count on the top of the cell flashes some random numbers before displaying the original count. Have any idea why this happens?? it happends with in a fraction of seconds

Here is the code what i have used

```
    var profile : HomeDTO = appD.homeDTO!.friendsDetailsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! HomeDTO
```

var cell : HomeCollectionViewCell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("HomeCollectionViewCell",     forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HomeCollectionViewCell

```
    self.loadImages(profile.profile_Thumb_image, imageView: cell.m_imgProfile, placeHolderImage: ProfilePlaceholderImage!)

    var strFirstName = profile.firstNameName
    var strSecondName = profile.lastName
    cell.m_lblName.text = strFirstName! + " " + strSecondName!

    var sharedInterests = String(profile.interestCount ?? 0)
    cell.m_btnSharedInterests.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.m_btnSharedInterests.layer.cornerRadius = cell.m_btnSharedInterests.frame.size.width/2
    cell.m_btnSharedInterests.userInteractionEnabled = false
    cell.m_btnSharedInterests.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    cell.m_btnSharedInterests.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.updateStatusColor(profile.isOnline!, cell: cell)
   cell.m_btnSharedInterests.setTitle(sharedInterests, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    return cell
```

Comment: Not without seeing the code and cell setup

Comment: Please see line in between first code snippet and second. it is how i create a cell

Answer (score 0):

Found myself what the issue was. I was using UIButton to show the count as it has some related actions following. I replaced it with a label & everything seems to be fixed.